# passing imageview through delegate

Tags: iphone

My programe does drag and move a little imageview by touch. When the location is decided, press a button to pass imageview to its superclass.

```
-(void) sendPosition:(CGPoint)position ;
```

when I run program for first, it runs ok but after I rerun the same process right after that, it occurs error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uhm..

```
-(void) sendPosition:(CGPoint) position withImageView:(UIImageView*) imageView;
```

maybe? (Sorry if this sounds stupid but I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly)